# Can't create new notebooks in jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

So I'm very new to programming and just started with jupyter. The thing is, I installed it from anaconda and everything seemed to work fine until I tried to create a notebook from Python 3. I got the following message:

[image]

I have the feeling that this is a trifle, but can't resolve it myself.

Anyone enlightened can give me some help with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide more details in your question (e.g. how exactly did you try to create the notebook, your settings, etc.).

Comment: Sure I can, thx for responding! I tried to create it from the tab "new", from where the other options apart from python 3 are text file, folder and terminal. The error is the same for all of them.  Apart from the pop un window of the error from above, it also opens a new tab totally blank and it inmediatly it's closed. In case this is useful, I can't either upload a file, it's loading it endlessly.  Regarding the settings, must be what's coming for default, since I didn't change anything, but to be honest I don't even know how can I check the settings options